# Having an old property name accepted - WFC/SOAP

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am using WCF and .NET 4.5, working with a WCF SOAP web service that's been in production for some time. Need to rename a property, but there is a small chance that some of production customers may have the old property name in their requests.

For example, if a property was called MyPoorlyNamedProperty and I renamed it to MyProperty, I wish both MyPoorlyNamedProperty and MyProperty in SOAP would de-serialize to that same property.

Is there a way to decorate a property of a type in WCF to specify an "alternative" accepted name for the renamed property?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any alternative name decoration or anything similar. If you wish to create a breaking-change, you need to do one of both:

1. Change the property name and notify your clients that the contract was changed and they need to prepare accordingly
2. Modify your API to accept both properties. In case it recieves a request with value for the old property, set this value to the new property.

Solution 2 is ugly and not the best practice. I don't recommend doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the second property to your model. And work with get; set; and the [DataMember attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    private string _surname;

    public string Surname { get { return this._surname; } set { this._surname = value; } }
    public string Lastname { get { return this._surname; } set { this._surname = value; } }
}
```